# I can't add row into String Collection Editor - VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a ComboBox in my form. There are a few rows, but I would like add some rows into (in the middle). In old VisualStudio (VS2018) I just add a row into "text" in built-in String collection editor.
In VS2019 a'm not able to add row into this list. Just at the end of list.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue. It will be fixed in v16.3. More information here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/705934/cant-add-a-row-into-string-collection-editor-for-c.html